# Marketing Cloud - retrieve automations via FuelSDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, automation

I'm trying to retrieve automations via C# FuelSDK. Retrieving emails and data extensions works fine but I'm having problem with automations. Please see my code bellow.

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.Name = "UserNameSoapBinding";
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);

        // Set the transport security to UsernameOverTransport for Plaintext usernames
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx");

        // Create the SOAP Client (and pass in the endpoint and the binding)
        SoapClient client = new SoapClient(binding, endpoint);

        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxx";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxx";
        APIObject[] Results;
        String requestID;
        String status;

        //Retrieve Automation

        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"xxx");

        file.WriteLine("--- Testing Automations ---");
        file.WriteLine("\r\n Get all of the Automations in an Account\r\n");

        // Instantiate the retrieve request
        RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest();

        rr.ObjectType = "Automation";//required
        rr.QueryAllAccounts = true;
        rr.Properties = new string[] { "Name", "CustomerKey" };//required

        status = client.Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out Results);

        foreach (Automation automation in Results)   //ERROR LINE
        {
            file.WriteLine("-- Name: " + automation.Name + " CustomerKey: " + automation.CustomerKey);
        }
```

I was following up the guide on [code.exacttarget.com](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/interacting-with-automation-studio-via-the-web-service-soap-api.html#Create) but if I run my code I'm getting error that I'm unable to cast object of type `FuelSDK.APIObject` to type `FuelSDK.Automation`.

[image: FuelSDK Exception]

Does anyone know how to handle this? Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem with adding `ProgramID` property and simple filter.